# Launching a C++ project from a .NET project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010

I have the following problem:

I have two projects, Project Game contains a game coded in C++ using the SDL library. Project Launcher is a C# .NET project which provides an interface from where to chose options before launching Project Game.

My questions are
A) How can I launch Project Game from within Project Launcher?
B) How can I pass arguments from Project Launcher to Project Game?

I haven't really found a clear cut solution for this, just whispers here and there. For the arguments there is the obvious, simply calling the .exe with arguments and reading them in C++, but I wonder if there is a cleaner way to do this that is built into .NET. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I find a solution for this I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET framework includes a class called Process, and it is included in the Diagnostics namespace.You should include the namespace, using System.Diagnostics then start your application like:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

// Prepare the process to run
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
// Enter in the command line arguments, everything you would enter after the executable name itself
start.Arguments = "readme.txt"; 
// Enter the executable to run, including the complete path
start.FileName = "notepad";
// Do you want to show a console window?
start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
start.CreateNoWindow = true;

//Is it maximized?
start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;

// Run the external process & wait for it to finish
using (Process proc = Process.Start(start))
{
     proc.WaitForExit();

     // Retrieve the app's exit code
     exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no IDE at the moment, so i'm not sure, but i remember that something like this should do the trick.

```
ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
//Add the arguments
proc.Arguments = args; 
//Set the path to execute
proc.FileName = gamePath;
proc.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;

Process.Start(proc);
```

EDIT:
My fault, i didn't see you were looking for methods that don't use passing arguments to the game process. I leave the reply just for reference to someone else! :)